# How to implement the multi-selection with angular either checkboxes / selectbox

Tags: select, checkbox

Can some one please suggest me the helpful directive to implement the feature with multi selection.

The i/p as array format. eg: `[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I used the below directives,

```
  - angular ui.select :
```

When I save it, sends the strings correctly.
 But When i get this values the select box is select with commas.

```
  - checklist-model : Saving properly. Get the value is coming as single string.
```

eg:

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Save: [4,6]
Get : 4,6 (selected as 3 items)
```